# High resolution issue with SSRS (Microsoft Report viewer)

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have a Winforms application (in Visual Studio 2015) that contains a Microsoft Report Viewer control that preview and prints report.

One user has 4K resolution monitor and when he runs the report it is shrunk to 2/3 size in microsoft report viewer control.

when I try to export this report into PDf it look proper.

The AutoScaleMode property of the form containing the Microsoft Report Viewer is set to "Font", although it doesn't seem to affect the report viewer if i change this.

I need some way to specify in the report viewer control itself that it should be rendered at 96dpi regardless of the system dpi setting. Is there any way to full-fill my  purpose. I have also attached sample report [Sample Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caVLk.jpg)

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

try to reduce the zoom level after detecting the resolution of the screen in javascript

You can use a hidden variable to track the resolution using the following DOM properties

document.body.clientwidth

document.body.clientHeight

In your reportviewer increase the "ZoomPercent" property to adjust the data on the complete page.
You can also increase the size of your reportviewer based on these settings

SizeToReportContent = True
Width = "width of hidden var from javascript"

Comment: I have an window application and I have also try to increase zoom level but still its show me white space. is there another way?

Comment: Did you increase the size of your reportviewer too? I mean the width and height

Comment: Yes, I have already increase size (height and width) of reportviewer control but it doesn't work.

Comment: I looked into your screenshot , the grayed area is the reportviewer , then in the page setup of rdlc file   set the paper size to letter with landscape mode .Increase the paper width and see if it works.

Comment: Also increase the width of tablix and the body of the report

Comment: No, only white portion is the report viewer and i have already set paper size to letter as well as A4 but I can't work.

Comment: Tablix size is same as report page size, if I increase more then that then It will display report in two pages